# JAXB - DO NOT unmarshall nested elements - possible?

Tags: java, jaxb

I've inherited a project which uses JAXB heavily to map XML messages onto Java objects. The problem I have is that some of the data which I receive (in this case nested XML of unknown form) has NOT to be unmarshalled, rather captured as a String.

An example will help

```
<a>
   <b></b>
   <c></c>
   <d>
       <!-- "Unknown" XML here -->
       <maybeE></maybeE>
       <maybeF></maybeF>
       <!-- etc etc -->
   <d/>
</a>
```

So I would want the JAXB to unmarshall "b" and "c" but "d" it would capture the nested XML as a string i.e. not parsed.

So calling:

```
getD()
```

Would return string:

```
"<maybeE></maybeE><maybeF></maybeF>"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't capture the nested content as a String, but you *can* capture it as a DOM, e.g.

```
@XmlRootElement(name="a")
public class A {

   @XmlElement
   private String b;

   @XmlElement
   private String c;

   @XmlAnyElement
   private List<Element> content;
}
```

Whatever `<a>` contains, which does not match `<b>` or `<c>`, will be stored under `content`.  You can then convert those `Element` objects into Strings, if you so wish.

Comment: Caused by: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
org.w3c.dom.Element is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces.

Comment: @Lawrence: Oops, my bad. Fixed.

Comment: @Lawrence: Glad I could help. This is where you click the tick symbol next to my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I found the above very useful; I had a similar mapping issue where I had HTML which was not escaped or encoded stored in an xml file - and I wanted to map this to a String property.

I used the annotation:

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name="operations")
@XmlAnyElement
private List<Node> operations;
```

Then used a transformer to print the node tree:

```
public String getOperationsAsString() throws Exception{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (Node node: operations) {
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
        transformer.transform(new DOMSource(node), new StreamResult(writer));
        builder.append(writer.toString());
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Andrew B: Your code can even be improved:

```
public String getOperationsAsString() throws Exception{
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
    for (Node node: operations) {
        transformer.transform(new DOMSource(node), new StreamResult(writer));
    }
    return writer.toString();
}
```

That way, you create the Transformer only once and you do not need the StringBuilder. StringWriter already writes into a StringBuffer internally.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, im blaming Intellij IDEA for making me sloppy :)

Answer (score 0):

You can keep unknown XML using the `@XmlAnyElement` annotation.  By default this will keep it as a DOM.  If you want it stored in another format (such as `String`) then you can specify a `DomHandler`:

**Full Example**

- [JAXB use String as it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13121914/jaxb-use-string-as-it-is/13123294#13123294)