# JAXB unmarshalling CDATA with HTML tags

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, cdata

**XML Structure:**

```xml
<rep>
<text type="full">[!CDATA[Demo, <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Search</a> thank you]]</text>
</rep>
```

I can able to parse this XML using JAXB, but the result is crappy, I have used `@XmlValue` to get the text element value.

**Java code:**

```java
@XmlRootElement(name = "rep")
public class Demo {
    @XmlElement(name = "text")
    private Text text;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return text.toString();
    }
}
```

```java
@XmlRootElement(name = "text")
public class Text {
    @XmlValue
    private String text;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[text=" + text + "]";
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[text= thank you]]]
```

But I need result like this, eg:

```
[!CDATA[Demo, <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Search</a> thank you]]
```

or

```
Demo, <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Search</a> thank you
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A CDATA section starts with `<![CDATA[` and ends with `]]>`, so your XML document should become:

```xml
<rep>
<text type="full"><![CDATA[Demo, <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Search</a> thank you]]></text>
</rep>
```

**Example Code**

```java
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Demo.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xsr = new File("src/forum16684040/input.xml");
        Demo demo = (Demo) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xsr);

        System.out.println(demo);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
[text=Demo, <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Search</a> thank you]
```

---

**UPDATE**

> thanks, But this case i can't able to edit the XML, bcoz i get XML
>   from third party API. is there any way to get the result, which i
>   except.

You can use `@XmlAnyElement` and specify a `DomHandler` to keep the DOM content as a `String`.  Below is a link to an answer that contains a full example:

- [JAXB use String as it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13121914/jaxb-use-string-as-it-is/13123294#13123294)

Comment: thanks, But this case i can't able to edit the XML, bcoz i get XML from third party API. is there any way to get the result, which i except.