# JAXB Unmarshalling an subset of Unknown XML content

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, sax, jaxb2

I have a requirement to `unmarshall` a subset of Unknown `XML` content, with that unmarshalled object, I need modify some contents and re-bind the same XML content(subset) with the Original  XML.

**Sample Input XML:**

```
<Message>
    <x>
    </x>
    <y>
    </y>
    <z>
    </z>
    <!-- Need to unmarshall this content to "Content" - java Object -->
    <Content>
        <Name>Robin</Name>
        <Role>SM</Role>
        <Status>Active</Status>
    </Content>
.....
</Message>
```

Need to unmarshall the `<Content>` tag alone, by keeping the other XML part as same. Need to modify the elements in `<Content>` tag and bind the modified XML part with the original as shown below:

**Expected Output XML:**

```
<Message>
    <x>
    </x>
    <y>
    </y>
    <z>
    </z>
    <!-- Need to unmarshall this content to "Content" - java Object -->
    <Content>
        <Name>Robin_123</Name>
        <Role>Senior Member</Role>
        <Status>1</Status>
    </Content>
.....
</Message>
```

**My Questions:**

1. What is the possible solution for this Requirement ? ***(Except `DOM` parsing - as XML contnet is very huge)***
2. Is there any option to do this in `JAXB2.0` ?

Please provide your suggestions on this.

Answer (score 1):

Consider cutting your source document down to size using the [StAX API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/package-summary.html).

For the given sample, this code creates a DOM document with a root element of the `Content` element:

```
class ContentFinder implements StreamFilter {
  private boolean capture = false;

  @Override public boolean accept(XMLStreamReader xml) {
    if (xml.isStartElement() && "Content".equals(xml.getLocalName())) {
      capture = true;
    } else if (xml.isEndElement() && "Content".equals(xml.getLocalName())) {
      capture = false;
      return true;
    }
    return capture;
  }
}

XMLInputFactory inFactory = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
XMLStreamReader reader = inFactory.createXMLStreamReader(inputStream);
reader = inFactory.createFilteredReader(reader, new ContentFinder());
Source src = new StAXSource(reader);
DOMResult res = new DOMResult();
TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer().transform(src, res);
Document doc = (Document) res.getNode();
```

This can then be [passed to JAXB](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXB.html#unmarshal%28javax.xml.transform.Source,%20java.lang.Class%29) as a [DOMSource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/dom/DOMSource.html).

Similar techniques can be used when rewriting the XML on output.

*JAXB doesn't seem to accept a `StreamSource` directly, at least in the Oracle 1.7 implementation.*

Comment: Is it possible to iterate over multiple <Content> nodes in a streaming fashion?  I have a gigantic XML file, and I want to extract nodes one by one without having to load the whole thing into memory.

Comment: I believe so. I'd likely use StAX events to create some sort of visitor pattern. The requirement is different enough to warrant its own question. You could likely still use the filter approach if you were willing to have all unmarshalled objects in memory at the same time.

Comment: Thanks, I created a [separate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23676373/how-do-i-iterate-over-nodes-in-a-huge-xml-in-a-streaming-fashion). I can't have all objects in memory, though, so I need to figure out a different approach.  Camel's [tokenizeXML](http://camel.apache.org/splitter.html) does exactly what I was, so I guess I can look into that.

Answer (score 0):

You can annotate an `Object` property on your class with `@XmlAnyElement` and by default the unmapped content will be captured as a DOM nodes.  If you specify a `DomHandler` on the `@XmlAnyElement` then you can control the format.  Here is a link to an example where the content is kept as a `String`.

- [JAXB use String as it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13121914/jaxb-use-string-as-it-is/13123294#13123294)