# How do I iterate over nodes in a huge XML in a streaming fashion?

Tags: java, xml, stream, iterator

I have a gigantic XML file, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
   </book>
   <book id="bk102">
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
   </book>
   [... one gazillion more entries ...]
</catalog>
```

I want to iterate over this file in a streaming fashion, so that I never have to load the whole thing into memory, something like:

```
InputStream stream = new FileInputStream("gigantic-book-list.xml");
String nodeName = "book";
Iterator it = new StreamingXmlIterator(stream, nodeName);
Document bk101 = it.next();
Document bk102 = it.next();
```

Also, I'd like this to work with different XML input files, without having to create specific objects (e.g. Book.java).

@McDowell has a promising approach that use `XMLStreamReader` and `StreamFilter` at https://stackoverflow.com/a/16799693/13365, but that only extracts a single node.

Also, [Camel's .tokenizeXML](http://camel.apache.org/splitter.html) does exactly what I want, so I guess I should look into the source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Book {
  // TODO: getters/setters
  public String author;
  public String title;
}
```

Assuming you want to process data as strongly typed objects you can combine StAX and JAXB using utility types:

```
  class ContentFinder implements StreamFilter {
    private boolean capture = false;

    @Override
    public boolean accept(XMLStreamReader xml) {
      if (xml.isStartElement() && "book".equals(xml.getLocalName())) {
        capture = true;
      } else if (xml.isEndElement() && "book".equals(xml.getLocalName())) {
        capture = false;
        return true;
      }
      return capture;
    }
  }

  class Limiter extends StreamReaderDelegate {
    Limiter(XMLStreamReader xml) {
      super(xml);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() throws XMLStreamException {
      return !(getParent().isEndElement()
               && "book".equals(getParent().getLocalName()));
    }
  }
```

Usage:

```
XMLInputFactory inFactory = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
XMLStreamReader reader = inFactory.createXMLStreamReader(inputStream);
reader = inFactory.createFilteredReader(reader, new ContentFinder());
Unmarshaller unmar = JAXBContext.newInstance(Book.class)
    .createUnmarshaller();
Transformer tformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
while (reader.hasNext()) {
  XMLStreamReader limiter = new Limiter(reader);
  Source src = new StAXSource(limiter);
  DOMResult res = new DOMResult();
  tformer.transform(src, res);
  Book book = (Book) unmar.unmarshal(res.getNode());
  System.out.println(book.title);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Can this be changed to be less staticly typed?  So that it could parse any XML file, without the Book.java requirement?

Comment: Sure. You have the DOM _Node_ from the _DOMResult_ so you can walk it or query it with XPath. You could skip the node generation and utilize the StAX API directly or use filters to build and process whatever generalized data structures you see fit. There should be enough information here to get you started.

Comment: Definitely :)  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Good answer, but sad that this simple operation is still so ugly in 2014, and that after waiting something like 4 years for lambdas, Oracle did not update most of the JDK libs to use them.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this precisely what the [SAX API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML) achieves ?

> SAX parsers have some benefits over DOM-style parsers. A SAX parser
>   only needs to report each parsing event as it happens, and normally
>   discards almost all of that information once reported (it does,
>   however, keep some things, for example a list of all elements that
>   have not been closed yet, in order to catch later errors such as
>   end-tags in the wrong order). Thus, the minimum memory required for a
>   SAX parser is proportional to the maximum depth of the XML file (i.e.,
>   of the XML tree) and the maximum data involved in a single XML event
>   (such as the name and attributes of a single start-tag, or the content
>   of a processing instruction, etc.).

I think you need to simply track each book `startElement()` call, and record the incoming elements/attributes from there. Process upon receipt of the corresponding `endElement()` call. Remember that `characters()` can be called multiple times across the same text node.

Comment: I probably could, but as far as I can see I have to handle every event type in each node, and rebuild those into the Node/Document I would return in my next() event.

Comment: That *is* true. You have to handle each element. Whether you rebuild into a new XML document, or (Say) construct a representative object (Book.java) on the fly is up to you. I would perhaps do the latter, and transfer out of the XML domain as you parse

Comment: I wasn't clear about this when I wrote the question, but I need to use this as a generic xml splitter. I won't be able to unmarshall into specific classes.

Answer (score 0):

Use SAX parser then. Check [SAX parser tutorial from Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html)

Answer (score -1):

You need to describe what the desired output of your process is, and what your technology constraints are.

Streaming in XSLT 3.0 is still bleeding edge, but many transformations can be expressed very easily. For example with Saxon-EE 9.5 you could compute the average price of the books in a streamed transformation as

```
<xsl:template name="main">
  <xsl:stream href="books.xml">
    <xsl:value-of select="avg(/books/book/price)"/>
  </xsl:stream>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: But I do describe it. Look at the example that I linked to. It   extracts a single <Content> node to a Document. I want to do that repeatedly with a number of nodes.

Comment: Sorry, but before I start writing code I ask for a better specification than that.