# Unmarshal xml response with dynamic XmlElements

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, unmarshalling

I have an xml response like below

```
<Item tstitem="123">
        <a1>
          <v1>56142587</v1>
          <v2>56265082</v2>
          <v3>56265097</v3>
          <v4>56326952</v4>
          ...
        </a1>
      </Item>
```

Here, these variables can be dynamic based on the request. How to unmarshal them into java objects.

I am using below code for individual variable

```
@Data
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class A1 {
    @XmlElement(name = "v1")
    private String v1;
}
```

Please help me here to hold all the variables at a time without writing individual variable names. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think you can do that.  you may need to extract the xml elements with xpath or similar. See here maybe - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16796418/jaxb-unmarshalling-an-subset-of-unknown-xml-content