# Jersey: marsheling and unmarsheling xml within other xml

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, jersey, marshalling

**The essence of question briefly:**

1) How to pun one xml, which should be wrapped by CDATA, inside other xml in Jersey?

2) How to avoid converting **"<"** into **"& lt;"** and **">"** into **"& gt;"** during Marshalling?

**More details:**

I need to send XML to external server

This XML should be in the following format:

```
<root>
   <element1>some value</element1>
   <element2>
      <![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
      <innerXlmElement>
         <item>
            <itemElement1>1</itemElement1>
            <itemElement2>1</itemElement2>
         </item>
         ...
         <item>
            <itemElement1>n</itemElement1>
            <itemElement2>n</itemElement2>
         </item>
      </innerXlmElement>]]>
   </element2>
</root>
```

That is one of the elements inside of external XML should be another XML, wrapped by CDATA.

First of all I made following bean:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "root")
public class Req {

   protected String element1;
   protected Element2 element2;

   @XmlElement(name = "element1")
   public String getElement1() {
      return element1;
   }

   public void setElement1(String element1) {
      this.element1 = element1;
   }

   @XmlElement(name = "element2")
   public Element2 geElement2() {
      return element2;
   }

   public void setElement2(Element2 element2) {
      this.element2 = element2;
   }

   public static class Element2{

   protected InnerXlmElement innerXlmElement;

   @XmlElement(name = "innerXlmElement")
   public InnerXlmElement getInnerXlmElement() {
      return innerXlmElement;
   }

   public void setInnerXlmElement(InnerXlmElement innerXlmElement) {
      this.innerXlmElement = innerXlmElement;
   }

   public static class InnerXlmElement{
      protected Item[] item;

   @XmlElement(name = "item")
   public Item[] getItem() {
      return item;
   }

   public void setItem(Item[] item) {
      this.item = item;
   }

   public static class Item{

      protected String itemElement1;
      protected String itemElement2;

      @XmlElement(name = "itemElement1")
      public String getItemElement1() {
         return itemElement1;
      }

      public void setItemElement1(String itemElement1) {
         this.svcId = itemElement1;
      }

      @XmlElement(name = "itemElement2")
      public String getItemElement2() {
         return itemElement2;
      }

      public void setItemElement2(String itemElement2) {
         this.itemElement2 = itemElement2;
      }
   }
}
```

Generated XML, which have been sent to external server during request, looked like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
   <element1>3324</element1>
   <element2>
      <innerXlmElement>
         <item>
            <itemElement1>1</itemElement1>
            <itemElement2>2</itemElement2>
         </item>
      </innerXlmElement>
   </element2>
</root>
```

Of course, generated internal XML wasn't wrapped by CDATA and it hadn't  first tag.

**So, the question is how wrap XML element by CDATA with Jersey?**

Also, I tried solve that problem rudely. I made internal XML by hand and put it to "Req" bean like String:

```
Req req = new Req();
req.setElement1("some value");
StringBuilder element2= new StringBuilder();
xmlServiceInfo.append("<![CDATA[<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?><innerXlmElement><item><itemElement1>1</itemElement1><itemElement2>2</itemElement2></item></innerXlmElement>]]>");
req.setElement1(element2.toString());
...
```

After that manipulation, I have such XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
   <element1>some value</element1>
   <element2>
      &lt;![CDATA[&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot; ?&gt;&lt;innerXlmElement&gt;&lt;item&gt;&lt;itemElement1&gt;1&lt;/itemElement1&gt;&lt;itemElement1&gt;2&lt;/itemElement2&gt;&lt;/item&gt;&lt;/innerXlmElement&gt;]]&gt;
   </element2>
</root>
```

Can somebody can tell me, how to avoid converting **"<"** into **"& lt;"** and **">"** into **"& gt;"** during Marshalling?

**---------- UPDATE (14.01.14) ----------**

I have tried ["JAXB use String as it is" solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13121914/jaxb-use-string-as-it-is)

So, first of all I changed type of element2 to String and added @XmlAnyElement annotation to it in my request bean:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "root")
public class Req {

   protected String element1;
   protected String element2;

   @XmlElement(name = "element1")
   public String getElement1() {
      return element1;
   }

   public void setElement1(String element1) {
      this.element1 = element1;
   }

   @XmlAnyElement(value=CDATAHandler.class)
   public String getElement2() {
      return element2;
   }

   public void setElement2(String element2) {
      this.element2 = element2;
   }
```

Then I did own implementation of DomHandler [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13121914/jaxb-use-string-as-it-is/13123294#13123294):

```
public class CDATAHandler implements DomHandler<String, StreamResult> {

  private static final String START_TAG = "<![CDATA[<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>";
  private static final String END_TAG = "]]>";

  private StringWriter xmlWriter = new StringWriter();

  public StreamResult createUnmarshaller(ValidationEventHandler errorHandler) {
     return new StreamResult(xmlWriter);
  }

  public String getElement(StreamResult rt) {
     String xml = rt.getWriter().toString();
     int beginIndex = xml.indexOf(START_TAG) + START_TAG.length();
     int endIndex = xml.indexOf(END_TAG);
     return xml.substring(beginIndex, endIndex);
  }

  public Source marshal(String n, ValidationEventHandler errorHandler) {
     try {
        String xml = START_TAG + n.trim() + END_TAG;
        StringReader xmlReader = new StringReader(xml);
        return new StreamSource(xmlReader);
     } catch(Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
     }
  }
}
```

After that changes Jersey became to throw exception (javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: HTTP 500 Internal Server Error). Here is StackTrace:

```
org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:226)
org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:655)
org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:652)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:422)
org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:652)
org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:412)
action.BaseExecutor.execute(BaseExecutor.java:42) [my method, where I invoke Jersey]
...
```

I put breakpoints to all methods in my handler, and non of them did not work.

If I remove @XmlAnyElement annotation, all will be fine (of course, except that Jersey will send wrong XML with "& lt;" and "& gt;" escaping).

**---------- UPDATE (15.01.14) ----------**

I debbuged Jersey and find root exception:

```
javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2: unable to marshal type "java.lang.String" as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation]
```

Comment: From the perspective of `<element2>` the content is just a string, which happens to be an XML document. If you really must format it as a CDATA section, this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136375/how-to-generate-cdata-block-using-jaxb) has lots of possible solutions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JAXB use String as it is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13121914/jaxb-use-string-as-it-is)

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan I have tried [your solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13121914/jaxb-use-string-as-it-is). But in that way Jersey became to throw exception (javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: HTTP 500 Internal Server Error). I would appreciate if you suggest me what could be the problem or which way I should look for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by change Jersey JAXB default implementation to MOXy.

Ok, I think, I can delete my question, because all problems, that I had duirind investigation of my issue, have been already answered on several other questions.